# copying a dict leaving out one (key, val) pair

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, copying

In Python 3, how do I copy a dictionary leaving out just one element? Data sharing among the two dicts is fine for me.
Currently I have this code in mind:

```
def copy_leaving_out(dictionary, key):
    return {k: v for k, v in dictionary if k != key}
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

EDIT: I forgot to use `dictionary.items()` instead of `dictionary`, please consider the following code instead of the previous one:

```
def copy_leaving_out(dictionary, key):
    return {k: v for k, v in dictionary.items() if k != key}
```

Comment: `k,v in dictionary` produces an error if you had tried it. you need `dictionary.items()` - why not debug your code yourself - if you know of the error, why not post the stacktrace/error message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a dictionary comprehension is fine (and pythonic). However, to iterate over the key/value pairs you need to call `dictionary.items()`:

```
def copy_leaving_out(dictionary, key):
    return {k: v for k, v in dictionary.items() if k != key}
```

If you want to be more explicit, you can also use `dictionary.copy()` to create a shallow copy of the dictionary, then remove the needed key:

```
def copy_leaving_out(dictionary, key):
    copy = dictionary.copy()
    del copy[key]
    return copy
```

Performance-wise, the second version appears to be noticeably faster, probably because it doesn't involve key comparisons:

```
In [14]: d = {k: k for k in range(200)}

In [15]: %timeit copy_leaving_out_dc(d, 100)
13.9 µs ± 724 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [16]: %timeit copy_leaving_out_copy(d, 100)
738 ns ± 4.45 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loopseach)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the performances. On the contrary the dict comprehension of the first solution is an inlined alternative which may be satisfactory when dealing with small dicts.

Answer (score 1):

Use `items()` functions in `dictionary comprehensions` to get key and value and finally using `if` clause -

```
d={'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
key_remove = 'a'
d_out = {k:v for k,v in d.items() if k != key_remove }
print(d_out)
    {'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to use a dictionary comprehension. It would suffice just to drop this key.

```
d = {1: 10, 2:20, 3:30}
res = d.copy()
res.pop(1)
10
res
{2: 20, 3: 30}
```